# Strange downvote behaviour

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, downvote-reason

This morning I opened my account on stackoverflow and I saw that 39 of my last answers have been suddenly downvoted. All one after the other, without any comment, without any explanation. All the answers I have now checked turned to 0 score (+1 / -1).

What have happened? I can't understand. Aren't upvote and downvote supposed to work as negative/positive feedback on the quality of an answer? A massive update of 39 answers in a few seconds is not a feedback at all in my opionion!

Comment: Yes, it looks like serial downvoting. It will probably be reversed automatically tomorrow morning. Just wait. If it's still there after 48 hours then flag one of your posts for mod attention and explain.